# export xml file from database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I tried the following code for exporting csv, xls, txt & xml files from the mysql database.

```
<?php
    include("includes/config.php"); 

    if($_POST["frmDownloadFiles"]){ 
        $output = "";
        $line_termineted="\n";

        if( $_POST["frmDownloadFiles"] =="CSV") {
            $field_termineted= ","; 
        }
        if( $_POST["frmDownloadFiles"] =="XLS") {
            $field_termineted= "\t"; 
        }
        if ($_POST["frmDownloadFiles"] =="TXT") {
            $field_terminated= "    ";
        } 
        if ($_POST["frmDownloadFiles"] =="XML") {
            $field_terminated= "\t";
        }
        $enclosed='';
        $escaped="\\";

        $export_schema = "Name".$field_termineted."Code".$field_termineted."Email".$field_termineted."Designation".$field_termineted."Salary";
        $dataQuery = doSelectCsv();
        //$handle = fopen($dataQuery, "w+");
//      while ($strBookData = fputcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) {       //  To get Array from CSV
//            $strDatas[] = $strBookData;
//        }
//      printArray($strDatas); exit;
        $strDatas = array();
        $strDatas = $dataQuery;
        //printArray($strDatas); exit;  
        $output.= $export_schema;
        //printArray($field_termineted);
        $p=0;
        for($k=0; $k<count($strDatas); $k++) {
            $p++;
            if( $_POST["frmDownloadFiles"] =="CSV") {
                $output.= $line_termineted;
            }
            if( $_POST["frmDownloadFiles"] =="XLS") {
                $output.= $line_termineted;
            }
            if( $_POST["frmDownloadFiles"] =="TXT") {
                $output.= $line_termineted;
            }
            echo "<employee_details>"; 
            if( $_POST["frmDownloadFiles"] =="XML") {
                echo "<Row>"; 
                echo "<name>" . $strDatas[$k]['0'] . "</name>";
                echo "<code>" . $strDatas[$k]['1'] . "</code>";
                echo "<mail>" . $strDatas[$k]['2'] . "</mail>";
                echo "<designation>" . $strDatas[$k]['3'] . "</designation>";
                echo "<salary>" . $strDatas[$k]['4'] . "</salary>"; 
                echo "</Row>";
            }
            echo "</employee_details>";
            $output.=$enclosed.$strDatas[$k]['0'].$enclosed.$field_termineted;
            $output.=$enclosed.$strDatas[$k]['1'].$enclosed.$field_termineted;
            $output.=$enclosed.$strDatas[$k]['2'].$enclosed.$field_termineted;
            $output.=$enclosed.$strDatas[$k]['3'].$enclosed.$field_termineted;
            $output.=$enclosed.$strDatas[$k]['4'].$enclosed.$field_termineted;
        }

        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        if( $_POST["frmDownloadFiles"] =="CSV"){
            header("Content-Type: application/csv");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report".date("d_m_Y_H_i_s").".csv");
        } 
        if( $_POST["frmDownloadFiles"] =="XLS") {
            header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
            header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=report".date("d_m_Y_H_i_s").".xls");
        }
        if( $_POST["frmDownloadFiles"] =="TXT") {
            header("Content-Type: application/txt");
            header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=report".date("d_m_Y_H_i_s").".txt");
        }
        if( $_POST["frmDownloadFiles"] =="XML") {
            header("Content-Type: application/xml");
            header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=report".date("d_m_Y_H_i_s").".xml");
        }

        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Content-Length: ".strlen($output));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        echo $output;
        exit;
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Export Files</title>
<link href="css/export.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
<form id="frmEmployee" name="frmEmployee" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validation();">
<div class="all">
<div class="alls">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="top">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div class="text" align="center">
          <p class="det">DOWNLOAD FILES</p>
        </div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div class="nnn">
        <div class="name">Download CSV file:</div>
        <div class="field">
          <label>
          <input type="submit" name="frmDownloadFiles" id="frmDownloadFiles" value="CSV" class="subb" />
          </label>
        </div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div class="nnn">
        <div class="name">Download excel file:</div>
        <div class="field">
          <label>
          <input type="submit" name="frmDownloadFiles" id="frmDownloadFiles" value="XLS" class="subb" />
          </label>
        </div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div class="nnn">
        <div class="name">Download text file:</div>
        <div class="field">
          <label>
          <input type="submit" name="frmDownloadFiles" id="frmDownloadFiles" value="TXT" class="subb" />
          </label>
        </div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div class="nnn">
        <div class="name">Download xml file:</div>
        <div class="field">
          <label>
          <input type="submit" name="frmDownloadFiles" id="frmDownloadFiles" value="XML" class="subb" />
          </label>
        </div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
      </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The first three works correctly, but xml cannot export from database. Please find my error and help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: What the error exactly? You have no file? You have blank file? You have blank page?

Comment: You want to export the data from mysql db into a specific xml format, using php??

Comment: The nature of this question means you will likely get down-voted. Try and give a more specific boil down. A lot of SO users will not bother to trawl through your code and run it themselves. You would be better off posting just the offending segment with more details on what errors/issues you have.

Comment: when download the xml file, it saves as a text file. this is my problem sir...

Comment: May be this can help you 
http://davidwalsh.name/backup-database-xml-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For exporting data from mysql in the xml using php,
try this code:

```
<?php
$dbh=mysql_connect($localhost, $username, $password) or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 12345_flv.flv WHERE enabled = '1' ORDER BY id DESC") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  

$string = '<videos><updated>2010-07-20T00:00:00Z</updated><video>';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $id=$row['id'];
    $title=$row['title'];
    $string .='<id>'.$id.'</id>';
    $string .='<title>'.$title.'</title>';
}
$string .='</video></videos>'; 
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
Header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $xml->asXML();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because for other methods than XML you store the result inside the `$output` variable (the variable you print at the end). For the XML format however, you just echo the result (not use `$ouput .= '<Row>'` for example).

Use the `header` function in PHP before any previous output (e.g., made by `echo`).
Replace your:

```
echo "<employee_details>"; 
if( $_POST["frmDownloadFiles"] =="XML") {
    echo "<Row>"; 
    echo "<name>" . $strDatas[$k]['0'] . "</name>";
    echo "<code>" . $strDatas[$k]['1'] . "</code>";
    echo "<mail>" . $strDatas[$k]['2'] . "</mail>";
    echo "<designation>" . $strDatas[$k]['3'] . "</designation>";
    echo "<salary>" . $strDatas[$k]['4'] . "</salary>"; 
    echo "</Row>";
 }
 echo "</employee_details>";
```

With

```
$output .= "<employee_details>";
if( $_POST["frmDownloadFiles"] =="XML") {
    $output .= "<Row>";
    $output .= "<name>" . $strDatas[$k]['0'] . "</name>";
    $output .= "<code>" . $strDatas[$k]['1'] . "</code>";
    $output .= "<mail>" . $strDatas[$k]['2'] . "</mail>";
    $output .= "<designation>" . $strDatas[$k]['3'] . "</designation>";
    $output .= "<salary>" . $strDatas[$k]['4'] . "</salary>";
    $output .= "</Row>";
}
$output .= "</employee_details>";
```

Comment: how can i export excel file with same code. please help me